# Checking for unique date/time with laravel validation

Tags: php, mysql, validation, laravel

Im learning laravel validation. My goal is to be able to check my events table in the database to make sure there is not an event with same date and time. There can be more than one event on a date but not more than one event at the same time. If there is i want to kickback the request with an error or be able to pass if available. The question is what is the best method to do this, in the Request or in the controller?

Comment: Have you looked at the Laravel documentation for the Validation component? https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#available-validation-rules

Comment: I just watched the laracasts video for validation. I just looked at your link, so i could do something like this example?  'myFormField' => 'exists:MyTable,MyColumn,(Whats this?),Constraint'.....  what is the third paramater?

Comment: You’d probably want to use the `unique` rule if you only want one event per date.

Comment: There can be two events on the same date, but they need to be a different times. I can achieve that with the exists thing still?

Answer (score 3):

Try this rule:-

```
protected $rules = [
    'event_date' => 'date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s|required|unique:event_table',
    ..
];
```

Hope it will help you :)